# Why so many null references in Hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable

[image]

I was trying to debug the Hashtable contents and got curious why there are so many Null references init.

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: Basically they're entries that aren't in use yet.

Comment: What you see are unused rows.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat new HashTable();

Comment: @mlecz Really ?

Comment: `null` generally means unset, which is what it means here. There is no value in that location in the array.

Comment: To debug any class, you need an understanding of its inner workings. So you should first read up on hash tables in general, and then study the Java Hashtable source code. After that, the issue should become pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how Hash tables work. [For reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

> In computing, a hash table (hash map) is a data structure which
> implements an associative array abstract data type, a structure that
> can map keys to values. A hash table uses a hash function to compute
> an index into an array of buckets or slots, from which the desired
> value can be found.

There are normally more buckets than values, that's why some buckets are empty.

This is important for performance of the hash table.

> A critical statistic for a hash table is the load factor, defined as
>
> load_factor=n/k
>
> where n is the number of entries occupied in the hash table. k is the number
> of buckets. As the load factor grows larger, the hash table becomes
> slower, and it may even fail to work (depending on the method used).
> The expected constant time property of a hash table assumes that the
> load factor is kept below some bound. For a fixed number of buckets,
> the time for a lookup grows with the number of entries and therefore
> the desired constant time is not achieved.

Comment: Will these null entries will be part of count(size)? If Yes why? And how do I get non-null entries size?

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay, no they won't be in size() result. Even when you loop over the table they won't appear.

Comment: Hi Joey, the size is returning including the null entries.

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#size()

Comment: @kutschkem, Returns the number of keys in this hashtable(Got it). But if you check Dictionaries<K,V> size (Returns the number of entries (distinct keys) in this dictionary.)

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay In your screenshot there are 10 entries and 26 buckets. size() should return 10.

Comment: @kutschkem, I specifically checked while debugging the last set, then only I concluded that it is including the null references as well while calculating the size.

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay Hashtable is literally keeping a count on how many entries have been added, and returns that if you call size(). http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Hashtable.java   Just to check, I wrote a test application that initialized a Hashtable with capacity 40, added one element, and then printed the output of size(). size() returned 1, not 40.